# error restarting MySQL 5.7 after adding innobuffer pool size in my.cnf

Tags: mysql, innodb, my.cnf

so I modified my innodb buffer pool size like so: SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size = 26843545600;

then added it to my.cnf

innodb_buffer_pool = 26G

but when when I restarted the service, I get the error:

"*Job for rh-mysql57-mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status rh-mysql57-mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.*"

it's only when I remove that entry that it restarts again..

error log shows it as:

-- Unit rh-mysql57-mysqld.service has begun starting up.
May 15 14:15:00 ourserver206 mysqld-scl-helper[3111]: Initialization of mysqld failed: 0
May 15 14:15:00 ourserver206 systemd[1]: rh-mysql57-mysqld.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 15 14:15:02 ourserver206 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL 5.7 database server.
-- Subject: Unit rh-mysql57-mysqld.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd

### -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel

### -- Unit rh-mysql57-mysqld.service has failed.

-- The result is failed.
May 15 14:15:02 ourserver206 systemd[1]: Unit rh-mysql57-mysqld.service entered failed state.
May 15 14:15:02 ourserver206 systemd[1]: rh-mysql57-mysqld.service failed.
May 15 14:15:02 ourserver206 systemd[1]: rh-mysql57-mysqld.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
May 15 14:15:02 ourserver206 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL 5.7 database server...
-- Subject: Unit rh-mysql57-mysqld.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd

### -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel

-- Unit rh-mysql57-mysqld.service has begun starting up.
May 15 14:15:03 ourserver206 sudo[3234]:  who_dat : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/etc/opt/rh/rh-mysql57/my.cnf.d ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe
lines 2583-2633/2633 (END)

Answer (score 0):

You must spell out the full variable name in the config file the same way that you used it in the `SET GLOBAL` command:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 26G
```

If you leave off the "_size" part, the variable name is not recognized.

If you view the MySQL error log file, you will probably see an error about "unknown variable".

Comment: Thanks Bill... you are correct.. it was a typo.. too tired.. LOL.. thanks again

Comment: @Janette, I'm glad to help. Can you please accept this answer if it helped you? Otherwise this question will remain "open" forever.